# Efficient curve fitting, and quantum computers

Tags: algorithms, numerical-methods, quantum-computation

I have a two part question concerning curve fitting to N parameters using computers.
First, is the time to find a curve fit to N data points proportional to N or is it worse?
Second, is this class of problem one which quantum computers could better solve?

Comment: There are many methods for fitting data. Most of them will process the entire list of provided data. The number of data points will affect the speed. I noticed that this site does not always provide solutions regarding curve fitting but that is just an impression.

Comment: I'm not so much interested in specific solutions but the algorithmic efficiency of solutions and whether they are amenable to QC speedup

Comment: There is a paper in the provided link, but I have no access to its contents, still, it may be of value:http://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.109.050505